# How do I reduce gif size when using Gif Brewry?

Tags: video, animation

I use gif brewry, and it seems to generate very large animated gif files; i'm looking to reduce their size - how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d say there are basically three things that impact the file size of a GIF.

- The **number of colors** in the GIF — The more colors there are in a GIF, the higher the file size.
- The **dimensions** of the GIF — Tumblr requires the width to be less than 500px, so at least start there. I think around 450px is a great size. However, don’t forget you can use the crop feature to just highlight the action.
- The **number of frames** — The number of frames you can use is highly dependent on the above two points.

The three items above mirror [the advice that the vendor gives](http://gifbrewery.com/post/39564982268/can-you-recommend-a-good-length-of-clip-to-keep-gifs) and you can use the GifBrewery preferences to help reduce the colors by processing it lightly or using dithering algorithms:

[image: gif brewery preferences screen]